# renderd not rendering

Tags: mapnik, rendering

I followed the instructions [manually building a tile server](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-14-04/) and ran in some problems.

When entering http://localhost:8080/osm_tiles/0/0/0.png

`renderd` shows this:

```
renderd[263]: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 22, number 9
renderd[263]: DEBUG: Got incoming request with protocol version 2
renderd[263]: DEBUG: Got command RenderPrio fd(22) xml(default), z(0), x(0), y(0), mime(image/png), options()
renderd[263]: DEBUG: Failed to read cmd on fd 22
renderd[263]: DEBUG: Connection 8, fd 22 closed, now 8 left
```

It seems renderd is aware of the request, but there do never appear some files in `/var/lib/mod_tile`. The `error.log` of the apache webserver shows:

```
debug: init_storage_backend: initialising file storage backend at: /var/lib/mod_tile
[Mon Jun 01 12:33:15.828298 2015] [tile:info] [pid 104:tid 140230287886080] [client 172.17.42.1:60074] tile_storage_hook: handler(tile_serve), uri(/osm_tiles/0/0/0.png)
[Mon Jun 01 12:33:15.828355 2015] [tile:info] [pid 104:tid 140230287886080] [client 172.17.42.1:60074] Requesting style(default) z(0) x(0) y(0) from renderer with priority 5`
```

and then responds me with a `404 Page not found`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue happened due to an error in my configuration of *renderd* in `/usr/local/etc/renderd.conf`. Parts of the configuration file looked like th following snippet:

```
[renderd]
socketname=/var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
num_threads=4
tile_dir=/var/lib/mod_tile
stats_file=/var/run/renderd/renderd.stats

;[renderd01]
;iphostname=::1
;ipport=7654
;num_threads=4
;tile_dir=rados://tiles/etc/ceph/ceph.conf
;stats_file=/var/run/renderd/renderd.stats

;[renderd02]
;iphostname=::1
;ipport=7654
;num_threads=8
;tile_dir=memcached://
;stats_file=/var/run/renderd/renderd.stats
```

Those lines beginning with `;` are commented out lines. Which is not allowed for lines containing `[something]` in those braces. So the solutions was to delete all lines beginning with `;`. After that, my *renderd* did it's job perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the 
`num_threads=4`
while trying to execute `render_list -n 10 -z 0 -Z 18 -a`

After changing `num_threads=10` the error disappeared.

The wired thing is day before it was `num_threads=4` and it did run with 
`render_list -n 6 -z 0 -Z 18 -a` and `render_list -n 7 -z 0 -Z 18 -a`
and i didnt understand why htop was showing only 4 cores working.

I left it to run at night, when i came in the morning to check the progress it looks like nothing happening all cores was on 0 and syslog dident show any activity.

Today i added cores to the vm tried to run `render_list -n 10 -z 0 -Z 18 -a`
and the error started. 
I changed to `num_threads=10` and the error stopped